# What is wrong in my code using DHT to compute convolution?

Tags: python, numpy, fft, convolution

The [Discrete Hartley Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Hartley_transform) can be computed as

```
import numpy as np

def dht(x:np.array):    
    X = np.fft.fft(x)
    X = np.real(X) - np.imag(X)
    return X

def idht(X:np.array):
    n = len(X)
    X = dht(X)
    x = 1/n * X
    return x
```

Circular convolution can be computed using the DHT according to a theorem illustrated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Hartley_transform#Properties), [here](http://dsp-book.narod.ru/TAH/ch04.pdf)(eq.4.7.22-4.7.25) and in many other places. I implemented the corresponding algorithm and compared it with circular convolution compute using the FFT, but the results are not even close. Why?

```
def conv(x:np.array, y:np.array):
    X = dht(x)
    Y = dht(y)
    Xflip = np.flip(X)
    Yflip = np.flip(Y)
    Yplus = Y + Yflip
    Yminus = Y - Yflip
    Z = 0.5 * (X * Yplus + Xflip * Yminus)
    z = idht(Z)
    return z


def test_conv():
    x = np.ones((5, ))
    y = np.copy(x)
    z = conv(x, y)
    z1 = np.real(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fft(x)*np.fft.fft(y)))
    np.testing.assert_allclose(z, z1, err_msg="test_convolution() failed")


if (__name__=='__main__'):
    test_conv()
    print("test_conv passed")
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ronf.py", line 35, in <module>
    test_conv()
  File "ronf.py", line 31, in test_conv
    np.testing.assert_allclose(z, z1, err_msg="test_convolution() failed")
  File "/home/andrea/vscode_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py", line 1528, in assert_allclose
    assert_array_compare(compare, actual, desired, err_msg=str(err_msg),
  File "/home/andrea/vscode_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py", line 842, in assert_array_compare
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: 
Not equal to tolerance rtol=1e-07, atol=0
test_convolution() failed
Mismatched elements: 5 / 5 (100%)
Max absolute difference: 5.65018378
Max relative difference: 1.13003676
 x: array([ 0.      ,  4.105099,  5.992006,  3.053079, -0.650184])
 y: array([5., 5., 5., 5., 5.])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is about the flipping part. To show with an example:

```
For a given array X_k, we need X_{-k} i.e., X_{N-k}.

N := 5
X_k := [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

np.flip does this:
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

However, this is not X_{N-k}! We need:
X_{N-k} = [0, 4, 3, 2, 1]

since:
for k = 0 => X[5-0] = X[0] = 0
for k = 1 => X[5-1] = X[4] = 4
...                         ...
for k = 4 => X[5-4] = X[1] = 1
```

That is, we assume periodicity of `N` s.t. `X[0] = X[N]` and so on, but `np.flip`'s result doesn't obey that. In short, first element should stay as is, others should flip.

One way to fix is to `np.roll` after your flips to rotate it 1 position:

```
def conv(x:np.array, y:np.array):
    X = dht(x)
    Y = dht(y)
    Xflip = np.roll(np.flip(X), shift=1)    # change is here
    Yflip = np.roll(np.flip(Y), shift=1)    # and here only
    Yplus = Y + Yflip
    Yminus = Y - Yflip
    Z = 0.5 * (X * Yplus + Xflip * Yminus)
    z = idht(Z)
    return z
```

Then I get:

```
>>> a = np.ones((5,))
>>> conv(a, a)
array([5., 5., 5., 5., 5.])
```

Comment: Thanks, nice answer! Rather than flipping and rolling, I could also do `Xflip =np.concatenate(X[0], np.flip(X[1:-1]), axis=None)`. What do you think? PS I fixed the errors in the question: you were right, they were typing mistakes.

Comment: @DeltaIV Sure, mine was a naive way to fix upon the already-flipped array. Yours is much more readable and perhaps more efficient! (but it should read `X[1:]` instead of `X[1:-1]` for the flip's argument to include the last value too).